# Insert text in Excel cell based on contents of other cell

Tags: string, excel

I have an Excel file, one column of which has a text string which contains either the letters "SV" or "ZS".
  I would like to populate a cell in another column with a string "SV-FOUND" or "ZS-FOUND", based on whether the cells in the first column contain the string "SV" or "ZS".

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Only just saw your answer, bernie. This is what I had tried:  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SV",'04-LB-06'!L3)),"SV FOUND", "Not Found" - So I could test for the existence of one string, but I didn't know how to add the second test.

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you? If so please mark as one as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used. It will help close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to combine the find with isnumber inside nested if statements:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("SV",A1)),"SV-FOUND",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ZS",A1)),"ZS-FOUND","Niether- FOUND"))
```

Comment: As a note, the `FIND` function is case sensitive and in most cases when searching for strings you'll want to use `SEARCH` instead which is not case sensitive. (However, based on the OP's description this will very likely work just fine.)

Comment: @tigeravatar I should have put the explanation in the answer.  I choose the find over the search because it appeared that the OP wanted case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

in the target cell type the following:

=if(A1 = "SV","SV-FOUND",if(A1 = "ZS", "ZS-FOUND",""))

Where A1 is the cell you are checking. You can then copy this code into all cells adjacent to the target.

EDIT:
If you want to find just the letters SV/ZS in ANY string of text then try the following:

if(A1 = ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SV",A1)), "SV-FOUND", IF(A1 = ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ZS",A1)), "ZS-FOUND",""))

Comment: That works great, Scott. Tigeravatar and User2977664 - I think you are searching for the full string "ZS" and "SV" , but I just want to check if the cell contains this substring.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column containing text strings are in column A, you can use this formula in your other column:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH({"SV","ZS"},A1),{"SV","ZS"})&"-FOUND","")
```